# JSON key, value formatting with R /choose a column as key and another one as value

Tags: r, json

I have a Data Frame `gscSocial`, which I am trying to transform into JSON:

```
  Date       totalReach
  2018-01-01       1069
  2018-01-02       3075
  2018-01-03       2674
  2018-01-04        876
```

This is what I am doing:

```
   gscSocialTotalReach   <- gscSocial %>%
                         as.tibble()%>%
                         gather(key=Date, value=totalReach) %>%
                         jsonlite::toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

The result is this:

```
[{"Date":"2018-01-01","totalReach":1069},{"Date":"2018-01-02","totalReach":3075},{"Date":"2018-01-03","totalReach":2674},{"Date":"2018-01-04","totalReach":876}]
```

But I would like this instead:

```
[{"2018-01-01":1069,"2018-01-02":3075,"2018-01-03":2674,"2018-01-04":876}]
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: `toJSON(setNames(as.list(dat$totalReach), dat$Date))` goes close. Taking your intended result, and trying to use `toJSON` with a named vector doesn't seem to work in reverse, as it drops the names. `toJSON(setNames(dat$totalReach, dat$Date))` for example.

Comment: THANKS!! got it with this: `toJSON(setNames(as.list(gscSocial$totalReach), gscSocial$Date),  auto_unbox = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @thelatemail advice the code is:

```
toJSON(setNames(as.list(gscSocial$totalReach), gscSocial$Date),  auto_unbox = TRUE)
```